# handle in a different way 2 similar urls in htaccess apache

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi guys i need help with apache htaccess.
I've this 2 url:

- test / en / guns2 / beretta/
- test / en / 1564 / vibram-beretta-m9a3/

how i can catch in a different way this 2 situations?

actually i've this htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/admin[NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/(it|en) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/en/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/([\w-]*)$ /test/index.php?detMod=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]*)$ /test/index.php?page=$2&category=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

But i need another rule for the case of number (1564) instead of the (guns2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\d+` to match only numbers and use `[\w-]+` to match alphanumerics, `_` and `-`:

```
^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/([\w-]*)$
```

and

```
^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]*)$
```

---

Suggested .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/admin[NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/(it|en) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/en/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/([\w-]*)$ test/index.php?detMod=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]*)$ test/index.php?page=$2&category=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: not working bro... with the url test / en / 1564 / vibram-beretta-m9a3/ apache get the rule with alphanumerics instead of the rule with numbers

Comment: Just remember that rule with numbers should be placed before other rule

Comment: Rules are working fine on my localhost. I have added suggested changes to your .htaccess in my answer. Good luck!

Comment: Make sure you are testing it right. I have copy/pasted my suggested rules on my local apahe and everything worked great